# Add letter to the right side without pushing text to left

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML here:

```
    <div class="last_img">
        <p>Galutinė žetono išvaizda:</p>
        <span class="zetin11">A</span>
        <span class="zetin12">A</span>
        <span class="zetin13">A</span>
        <span class="zetin14">A</span>
        <span class="zetin15">A</span>
        <img class="last_img_img" src="images/img1.png" alt="">
    </div>
```

When I write text, the text in span move to the left, so it goes outside of image. How can I only add letter to the right side, without moving text to the left ?

This is my css of `zetin11`:

```
position: relative;
    top: -125px;
    right: -79px;
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 18px;
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ Cia sukelk viska, tada iskart daugiau zmoniu pades :)

Comment: Have you tried changing the position to fixed or absolute?

Comment: @Twahanz With absolute text also moves to the left

Comment: Also with absolute text messes up on different resolutions

Answer (score 0):

From the Question what I understood is that you want to pull the A's to the right without moving the paragraph. If that's the Case then here is a

I just used the

```
span{
   float: right;
}
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rittamdebnath/fdhj1u6s/

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as follows :

HTML

```
<div class="last_img">
  <p>Galutinė žetono išvaizda:</p> <br />

  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img class="last_img_img" src="https://i.imgur.com/I86rTVl.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

   <!-- Seperate them into different classes to style them later on -->

  <div class="spancontainer">
    <span>A</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>A</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.last_img{
    width: 100%;
}

.imagecontainer{
  float: left;
}

.spancontainer{
  float: right;
}
```

[Click Here for JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/re4b8u57/#&togetherjs=JC1iRJ9QNF)

**Recap:** I separated both items into different divs so that I will take control over the divs using CSS.

I included a class for the first div named image container which is set to float left so that the image will stick to the left

and another div spancontainer which is set to float right so that it will stick to the right near the image.

I like setting a global div class so that I can encapsulate all the others inside it and have control on giving the global class also a specific width in the page itself... in such case I set it to 100% and I used the name you used 'last_img'
I also removed the zetin classes as you won't be needing them as long as you aren't going to style each span seperately ;)

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: So you want the image underneath the text ? floated on the right like this, I created a new JS Fiddle for you here >>> 

 [Click here for JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ericscicluna/8gmjf2zc/)